# How can i access my draft which disappeared when i uninstalled the app?

Tags: draft

I was using the WordPress App on my phone which had some drafts and unfinished posts saved in "Blog Posts" as local drafts. But due to some reason I uninstalled the app..When I installed it again, I could not find my drafts and unfinished posts. Any idea where I can retrieve them again?

Comment: Welcome to SE: WordPress development, if drafts und unfinished post were only saved on you phone they are gone. Do you have an old backup of your phone? If yes you  could restored it  and hoped that the data of the WordPress app will restored too.